# http bad request, can't find the bad character(s)

Tags: php, http, httprequest

Hello i'm using cakephp and i need to update the status throug an action method 
the method in the controller is this

```
function setEstado($id, $id_usuario, $estado,$vars) {
```

i'm using serialize to get all the fields of the form (when i update the status i need to update all the changes done, so... This is my request

> OrdenesReparaciones/setEstado/36725/46/6/_method=PUT&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bguardando%5D=&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bid%5D=36725&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bidusuarioa%5D=46&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bcliente_id%5D=14915&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bnumero%5D=220498&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Btipo%5D=Presupuesto&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bnro_orden_anterior%5D=&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bfecha%5D=19-08-2015&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bfecha_prometido%5D=20-08-2015&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bfecha_asignado%5D=31-08-2015&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bcliente%5D=EDUARDO+DO+CAMPO&data%5BCliente%5D%5Bdireccion%5D=&telefono=&celular=099668032&email=&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Barticulo%5D=MARTILLO&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bmodelo%5D=MD+908&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bmarca_id%5D=120&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bmarcass%5D=120&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bimportador%5D=R.+BALAGUER+S.A.&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bimportadors%5D=R.+BALAGUER+S.A.&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bdetalle_marca%5D=NEO&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bfecha_compra%5D=00-00-0000&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Blugar_compra%5D=&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bnro_comprobante%5D=&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5BPrecio_compra%5D=&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bdesperfecto%5D=&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Baccesorios%5D=&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bserie%5D=&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Barea_id%5D=4&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bsub_taller%5D=0&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bsubtaller_id%5D=&bitacora_add=&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bpresupuesto_taller%5D=R-C%2C+R-M%2C+INTERRUPTOR%2C+ASEGURAR+TROMPA%2C+2+RULEMANES%2C+CARBONES%2C+AROS+DE+COMPRESION%2C+LIMPIEZA%2C+LUBRICACION%2C+AJUSTE%2C+REPARAR+CONEXIONES&respuestos=&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bmonto%5D=0.00&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Brecibo_sena_id%5D=0&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bprecio_asignado%5D=4700.00&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Brecibido_por%5D=22&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bvino_por%5D=22&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Btipo_envio%5D=25&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bnro_remito%5D=&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bcant_llamados%5D=0&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bobservaciones%5D=5%25+26-08-2015+09%3A07%3A28+MAT+-+Bitacora+taller%3A+R-C%2C+R-M%2C+INTERRUPTOR%2C+ASEGURAR+TROMPA%2C+2+RULEMANES%2C+CARBONES%2C+AROS+DE+COMPRESION%2C+LIMPIEZA%2C+LUBRICACION%2C+AJUSTE%2C+REPARAR+CONEXIONES++++++26-08-2015+09%3A05%3A46+MAT+-+Cambio+precio%3A+4700.00++26-08-2015+09%3A01%3A52+MAT+-+Cambio+precio%3A+3200.00++19-08-2015+11%3A41%3A09+JORGE+-+Asignada+a+sector%3AINDUSTRIAL++19-08-2015+11%3A41%3A08+JORGE+-+Accesorios%3A+++19-08-2015+11%3A41%3A02+JORGE+-+Maquina%3A+MARTILLO++19-08-2015+11%3A40%3A39+JORGE+-+Se+cambió+tipo+de+orden+a+PRESUPUESTO+++++++++++++++++++++19-08-2015+11%3A40%3A13+SANTIAGO+-+Orden+creada++26-08-2015+09%3A07%3A28+MAT+-+CONFIRMADA&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Bdestino%5D=&data%5BOrdenesReparacion%5D%5Balerta%5D=

it have the following pattern Controller=OrdenesReparaciones action=setEstado id=36725 id_usuario=46 estado=6 vars=_method... 
i have the following error

> Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

I just don't know which is the special char that is damaging my request, i already replace %2F which is '/' with '-' in the dates values, but i can't see here which character should i replace, please, any ideas or advices will mean a lot for me.

Comment: If I were troubleshooting this, I would take apart the request and keep adding parts on until something breaks, at which point.. I know where the issue is. I would not ask this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: you say split the serialize string until i get the break?

Comment: this does not look like a serilized string...

Comment: `code`  location.href = url + $("#idusuarioa").val() + "/" + "3"+"/"+$("#frm2").serialize().split('%2F').join('-')